# Retrieving nth element with xsl:number

Tags: xml, xslt

In my XML document, I have note calls and endnote, obviously not at the same place in the doc. I can be sure that there is exactly the same number of `<notecalls>` elements and `<endnote>` elements. With a XSL, I would like to retrieve the content of the corresponding `<endnote>` (ie : the first `<notecall>` element goes with the the first `<endnote>` element and so on) to create a new element made up of a number and the content of the endnote.

I used the xsl:number function for that, as one can see below ; but the content of the note that is retrieved is always the first endnote element, although the re-numbering is correct in the output file. What am I missing here ?

Here is what my XML structure looks like :

```
<main_text>Some text<notecall>1</notecall> some other text </main_text>
<main_text>More and more long text<notecall>2</notecall> and more even</main_text>
<main_text>And some more again <notecall>3</notecall> etc…<main_text>

<endnote>The content of the first endnote</endnote>
<endnote>The content of the second one</endnote>
<endnote>The content of the third one</endnote>
```

And the relevant part from the XSL file :

```
<xsl:template match="notecall">
    <xsl:variable name="posit">
        <xsl:number level="any"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <seg>
        <xsl:value-of select="$posit"/>
        <note><xsl:value-of select="(//endnote)[$posit]"/></note>
    </seg>
</xsl:template>
```

I would like to have :

```
<p>Some text<seg>1<note>The content of the first endnote</note></seg> some other text</main_text>
<p>More and more long text<seg>2<note>The content of the second one</note></seg> and more even</main_text>
<p>And some more again <seg>3<note>The content of the third one</note></seg>  etc…</main_text>
```

But what I get is :

```
<p>Some text<seg>1<note>The content of the first endnote</note></seg> some other text</main_text>
<p>More and more long text<seg>2<note>The content of the first endnote</note></seg> and more even</main_text>
<p>And some more again <seg>3<note>The content of the first endnote</note></seg>  etc…</main_text>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use XSLT 2.0 or later change

```
<xsl:variable name="posit">
    <xsl:number level="any"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

to

```
<xsl:variable name="posit" as="xs:integer">
    <xsl:number level="any"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

Otherwise change `<xsl:value-of select="(//endnote)[$posit]"/>` to `<xsl:value-of select="(//endnote)[position() = $posit]"/>` as your variable is a result tree fragment and not a number, so to use it as the position you need to compare explicitly, or, alternatively, convert to a number with `<xsl:value-of select="(//endnote)[number($posit)]"/>`.

Comment: Simply : THANK YOU. That solves it, an I understood something.